# How many instances of View objects in MVC

Tags: java, model-view-controller, architecture, svg

I am trying to create a MVC application for editing SVG objects.
I have classes like `Circle`, `Rectangle`, `Text` as Model and `CircleView`, `RectangleView` and `TextView` as View.

*Is it correct from the point of view of MVC to have for each instance of a shape (for example `Circle`) to have an instance of a View (like `CircleView`)?*

That would mean for 100 shapes drawn on the canvas I will get 100 View instances.

Comment: Please note, that in modern interpretations of MVC pattern, the model is actually a layer. Not any single class or object. What people tend to call "models" are misnamed [domain objects](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DomainObject).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're misunderstanding the concept of MVC. Your view is typically your canvas, not your shapes. The shapes are parts of the model, and your XXXView classes should not exist.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, the `Model` can be understood as a set of graphical elements.

All your graphical elements like `Circle`, `Rectangle`, `Text` must implement some one interface (`GraphicalElement` for instance). And one `View` class that will be use these methods.

In your case I can introduce `GraphicalElement` interface with method

```
interface GraphicalElement {
    void draw(Graphich g);
}
```

And `View` will be iterate thorough all your  `GraphicalElement`s to display them

```
for (GraphicalElement ge : setOfElements) {
     ge.draw(graphics);
}
```

Comment: Calling "draw" method on a Model Object(GraphicalElement) ? Is that right from the point of view of MVC ?

Comment: I introduce `GraphicalElement` interface as additional (just for drawing). If the class implements `GraphicalElement` interface that does not mean that it is related to the model. Just in your case it is better to combine drawing and the implementation of models element in the same class (like Circle, Rectangle).